# Find lines without repeated text

Tags: regex, notepad++, regex-negation

I have problem with my work to find different line.
The example is number 4. How to get mark for number 4?

```
    Line Text
    1.   ABCDEFGHJK  ABCDEFGHJK
    2.   JKJKJKJKJK  JKJKJKJKJK
    3.   JLKIHWTWBE  JLKIHWTWBE
    4.   wieufhwiwe  iewfhweowi
    5.   LKHGSBNAAU  LKHGSBNAAU
    6.   uiedgei732  uiedgei732
```

Comment: formatting, title, tags

Answer (score 1):

Try searching for this regex:

```
^(\w+)\s((?!\1).)*$
```

It looks for a line `^`...`$` starting with a word `\w+`, captures that word `(`...`)` then looks for a space `\s` followed by a group of characters that are *not* the captured group `?!\1` but some other character `.`